# Solutions for object recognition on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am going to write a mobile application that recognizes images within a *closed* target group. I guess the group contains 20 to 50 comic-like images like [this](http://www.walldesk-hd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/super-mario-new-game-for-kids-picture-32-wallpaper-HD.png).

The application reacts if any of those targets are captured by the camera of the device. That's it.

There are some constraints, though.

- It should recognize *rotated* targets.
- It should recognize those with the different *perspectives* and *levels of light*.
- If it can handle with obstruction like fingers, I'll be happy with that. *(optional)*
- It should be easy to train. *(optional)*
- I'd prefer inaccurate but *fast* solutions. (no more than 3 seconds, maybe?)

I don't have sufficient time for the task and am kind of new to image-processing, so starting with OpenCV is time-consuming, apparently.

I'm looking forward to your suggestions.

Plus, the solutions do *not* have to be free.

---

### Edit:

In terms of our budget, I may have to ask my non-tech boss who doesn't likely know the common price. Just give me suggestions / offers regardless of the price then he's going to pick one.

Comment: Training a Haar classifier for OpenCV is not actually that hard. E.g. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEzm7L5zoZE . . . the time-consuming part of the problem is sourcing enough sample images to complete the training.

Comment: @NeilSlater, Nice video. So training itself seems to be straightforward with OpenCV. Amazing! I'll give it a try. Thank you a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Disclaimer: i work for Moodstocks*]

You should have a look at the [Moodstocks](https://moodstocks.com/) SDK. It fits most of your requirements:

- it's robust to lightning and perspective changes,
- it tolerates partial occlusion, for example by fingers,
- it require *no* training at all: you just upload (*index*) an image to make it instantly recognizable,
- it's extremely fast: the image matching is done locally, so on a modern smartphone you'll get a result in far less than 300ms.

The only issue is with the robustness to rotation: the Moodstocks SDK only supports *small* rotation (~30°). That being said, given the fact that you have a limited number of images, this can be easily solved in a rather brute-force fashion by indexing several instances of each image under different rotations!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Renon. I'm having fun with the trial, it's super easy and is really capable of partially occluded ones as you stated. Great work!